# C# - Calling a string from a different method?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, process.start

I know this is probably easy...but I am attempting my first application in C# (and very excited about it!).

I figured, on drop, I get the file path and make it a string, then call the string once the button is click. 
ANY ideas, references, other pages, or any info is gladly appreciated!

Though nominal...this is what I have so far for the button and dragdrop:

```
private void B1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(???);
    }
private void B1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] B1file = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    }
```

My goal is to create a program that a user can drag and drop any file they want into a button. Once dropped, the file name will paste to the button face (this.B1.Text) and the icon will paste to a pictureBox that floats over the button. Once button is clicked, the file path to the dropped file opens.

Comment: check my solution and tell me if something is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make your variable private in your class and then use it. Note: **B1_DragDrop** should run before **B1_Click**

```
private string[] B1file;
private void B1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in B1file)
    {
        Process.Start(item);
    }
}

private void B1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   B1file = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Props to Mohamad!